# Как управлять размерами svg иконки вставленой из спрайта посредством use?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

Есть созданный собственноручно `SVG-спрайт`, который содержит некоторое количество иконок. Иконки добавляются в `html` документ с помощью тега `use`. Таким образом:

```
<svg class='underline'>
    <use xlink:href='img/sprite.svg#mobile'/>
</svg>
```

Возник вопрос, как можно управлять размерами иконки?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью класса я смог добиться изменения цвета иконки, но изменить таким образом размер - не выходит.

```
.underline {
    width: 100%;
    fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью команды `scale(2)` - увеличит размер иконки в 2 раза, но иконка будет сдвинута по координатным осям, чтобы вернуть её на место нужно будет применить ещё одну команду трансформации  translate(x y)

```
<svg class='underline'>
    <use xlink:href='img/sprite.svg#mobile' transform="scale(2) translate(x y)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: извиняюсь, а это не костыльно?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  это наиболее правильный подход, ещё более правильный подход складывать в спрайт иконки нужного размера.

Comment: А если, скажем так, есть такого рода андерлайн, http://prntscr.com/j60q49 и нужно сделать что бы его ширина была 100%, текст уменьшиться по достижению определенного размера экрана, и ширина блока измениться. Лучше использовать background в таких случаях?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi затрудняюсь ответить, чтобы не ввести вас в заблуждение. Конечный результат зависит от многих параметров.  словами трудно дать исчерпывающий ответ без конкретного кода. Картинки недостаточно. Задайте новый вопрос, с кодом и чёткой формулировкой, что хотите получить на выходе.

Answer (score 1):

```
<svg width="160px" height="160px">
     <use xlink:href="img/icons.svg#krug"></use>
</svg>
```

Тоже отлично работает